# Removing all spatially related software from Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, proj

I managed to mess up my installation of `gdal`, `proj`, `qgis` and `sf`. I am not a hundred percent sure what I did wrong but I earlier today tried to update my system gdal installation by using the ubuntugis unstable ppa (Not sure if this is a good idea). Judging by the times I reinstalled linux, only because I broke all my spatial packages, I should already know how to handle this better. But I don't...

I also do not know how to provide really useful error messages or logs or system configurations to narrow down the problem. Many times I did a

```
sudo apt remove gdal-bin libgdal-dev proj-bin
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt remove qgis
...
```

and reinstalled everything.

However (and I do not know if this helps) when I start qgis from the command line I see this:

```
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

My Internet-Search did not yet help me a lot to e honest.
Also, when I try to install `sf` with `install.packages("sf")`, I see:

```
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /usr/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... no
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for linking:... yes
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available fur running:... ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `' to `'
no
```

So I guess there is something really wrong.

How can I go back to state 0?

It all just worked fine in the morning. I am super willing to uninstall qgis, sf, R, anything... But I do not yet again want to setup Linux. As this happens so often to me I tried looking into creating some ansible jobs to easier setup my PC. But that is not the real solution. And besides that I really want to understand how to narrow down problems like this more analytically rather than just wiping everything.

Comment: For QGIS I wouldn't use Ubuntu GIS anymore, the QGIS project installers are much more up to date and the install process is pretty easy: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

Comment: I actually used them haha

Comment: I think I did a really bad mix of everything

Comment: Why don't you reinstall Ubuntu one more time, then create a snapshot (or clone your hard drive) before installing GIS tools? That allows you to easily go back to the state before you installed the GIS related software.